# How to use DISTINCT in nested personal geodatabse SQL in ArcGIS

Tags: sql, syntax, distinct, arcgis

I have this Statement used in ArcGIS for a personal geodatabse. 
It selects the top three records in [MyColumn1], but not if the [MyColumn2] equals an inline variable.

```
[MyColumn1] in(SELECT TOP 3  ( [MyColumn1] ) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE [MyColumn2]  <> %Variable%
ORDER BY [MyColumn1] DESC)
```

But I also need to add a DISTINCT function because some times there are repeated values in [MyColumn1] so that 4 records are selected.

How to include DISTINCT in this expression so that ArcCrash and a personal geodatabase can handle it? There is a lot on this subject, but nothing specific to working Arc or at least access.

This doesn't work

```
[MyColumn1] in(SELECT TOP 3  ( [MyColumn1] ) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE [MyColumn2]  <> %Variable%
ORDER BY [MyColumn1] DESC 
DISTINCT [MyColumn1] )
```

Nor does this

```
[MyColumn1] in(SELECT TOP 3  ( [MyColumn1] ) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE [MyColumn2]  <> %Variable%
ORDER BY [MyColumn1] DESC 
GROUP BY [MyColumn1])
```

Comment: I am not to fluent in arcgis queries but in most query languages the distinct goes in the select. So Try: SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  [MyColumn1]

Comment: This still selects 4 records if there is a repeat in [MyColumn1]. The query doesn't error out though.

Answer (score 0):

Well since this isn't the full query your select top 3 is going to return 3 records, but if your MyColumn1 has duplicates and the select distinct returns one of those that has duplicate then both of those will be included in the In statement. For Example.

```
FirstName | LastName
Bob          doe
Billy        smith
Marie        Evans
Bob          Lock
```

if you then do
Select * from table where FirstName in (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 FirstName FROM table)

you will get all 4 records because your inner query will return ("Bob", "Billy", "Marie") and since your initial query (Select * from table where FirstName in ("Bob", "Billy", "Marie")) wants records that have those 3 first names, well they all have at least one of those names. the solution here would be this query.

Select Distinct FirstName from table where FirstName in (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 FirstName FROM table)

The problem with this is when you do a distinct you need to include all the column names in it so you will cannot get the last name column from this query.

Comment: I believe I now have syntax problems. Can you elaborate further on this?<br/>
    `SELECT DISTINCT [MyColumn1] FROM MyTable`  
    `WHERE [MyColumn1] in(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  ( [MyColumn1] )`  
    `FROM MyTable`  
    `HERE [MyColumn2]  <> 3`  
    `ORDER BY [MyColumn1] DESC )`  

This doesn't work...I get a syntax error.

Comment: well you dont really need to have a subquery at this point since you can just use your sub query as your main query. try this: SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 [MyColumn1] FROM MyTable WHERE [MyColumn2] <> 3 ORDER BY [MyColumn1] DESC

Comment: The problem may because arcgis requires DISTINCT, GROUP BY, and other functions to be in subquery format because of the forced SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE:

Comment: Yeah, that would be a problem if you cannot distinct your main select then you will always return all of the items that match your sub query.

Comment: Just found a ArcGIS proprietary function that solves the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used ArcGIS tool Delete Identical which deletes the first of multiple, identical records. HA. quite perfect.